# Using enum declared in class in the protocol of the class itself in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

How do we do something like forward declaration in Swift?

I have a protocol declared before a class, but protocol needs to use an enum (recordType) declared before the class:

```
protocol iCloudDelegate {
    func errorUpdating(error: NSError)
    func iCloudUpdated()
    func iCloudFetched(recordType: recordType)
}

class iCloud {

    enum recordType : String {
        case Payment = "Payment"
        case Subtype = "Subtype"
        case Types = "Type"
        case Entry = "Entry"
        case Repeat = "Repeat"
    }
}
```

Right now Swift compiler complains with **Use of undeclared type 'recordType'** error. In objective-C here we would place some kind of forward declaration, what about Swift?

As a side note question, you see that above I had to declare case Types, instead of Type, because "Type" is apparently a reserved case-word for enums. Is there any way to overcome this? (apart changing the name as I did of course)

Comment: Try `func iCloudFetched(recordType: iCloud.recordType)` for more info, Nested Types in Swift: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/NestedTypes.html

Comment: Oh my! That was really n00b of me, thanks! If you put this in an answer I will be happy to accept that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access types declared within another type (Nested Types), put surrounding type's name before nested type:

```
func iCloudFetched(recordType: iCloud.recordType)
```

For more information about Nested Types in Swift: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/NestedTypes.html